# Error while processing route: home No model was found for 'App.undefined'

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js, ember-data

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.1
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

Having an issue with what I believe is the belongsTo attribute on my user model. (This happens on my other belongsTo attributes within my application as well). I have a Django backend which returns a response when I comment out the network: attribute.

```
{
    email: "test@test.com",
    first_name: "Test",
    global_code: "daht64q691zy4k887ch",
    global_id: "GBID-USER-dat64q6917zy4k887ch",
    institution_gbid: "GBID-GINS-567j53ey0lojsu2kys",
    institution_name: "Some University",
    last_name: "Testing",
    network: { },
    view_policy: {
        capability: "system:view",
        description: "Anyone can view a user",
        hold: true,
        id: "daht64q691y4k887ch:system:view",
        values: ""
    }
}
```

Code for the User Model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
        first_name: DS.attr('string'),
        last_name: DS.attr('string'),
        global_id: DS.attr('string'),
        network: DS.belongsTo('basicgrouping')
        }):
```

Code for Basic Grouping model:

```
App.Basicgrouping = DS.Model.extend({
        global_id: DS.attr('string'),
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        gbid_code: function(){
            return getGBIDCode(this.get('global_id'));
        }.property('global_id')
    });
```

Debugging ember-data I placed a console.log() within the following code:

```
  relationshipsByName: Ember.computed(function() {
    var map = Map.create();

    this.eachComputedProperty(function(name, meta) {
      console.log(name, meta);
      if (meta.isRelationship) {
        meta.key = name;
        var relationship = relationshipFromMeta(this.store, meta);
        relationship.type = typeForRelationshipMeta(this.store, meta);
        map.set(name, relationship);
      }
    });
```

[image: Console response from the method]

This seems to show that the type of the object that it belongs to is not being found (Basicgrouping) as it's returning App.undefined.

My theory is it may have something to do when parsing the server response and maybe the payload response. This also happens in other belongTo relationships in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a file that was overriding some of the DS. methods and causing an empty type to be sent. I was in the process of removing use of the shim but didn't know that it was being used.

Thanks the Bmacs from the ember community for the help debugging the issue.